# how to create com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.list?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, day-cq

I am trying to create a list of type com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.list

[documentaion](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/diff-previous/changes/com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.List.html)  says that I can send one SlingHttpRequest in constructor and can create this list based on that request. But when I am trying to run my code its giving null pointer exception. My code is as follows

```
SlingHttpServletRequest request = jspContext.getRequest();
List list = new List(request);
```

StackTrace is empty because this exception is coming in some jar file.

StackTrace is as follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.List.generateId(List.java:380)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.List.<init>(List.java:193)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.List.<init>(List.java:180)
    at com.resmed.wuts.core.controller.BlogControllerTest.testGetCategoryBlog(BlogControllerTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: The request appears to be null.  Check the request/context.

Comment: I have checked request is not null because I am mocking it using mockito

Comment: How are you setting up your `jspContext`? Are you Mocking the `request` or the `getRequest()`? I agree with @HithamS.AlQadheeb, your request is `null`.

Comment: no its not null I got the reason for this error. It was coming because for testing purpose I should mock list also, I am new to mockito so I did not know this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem.
Since I was trying to create the above list for testing, that is why it was giving null pointer instead it needs to be mocked as follows

```
List list = mock(List.class);
```